# Operations amongst different order of little o

Tags: real-analysis

I'e the following expression:

$$
\frac{a \, t + o(t)}{t} + \frac{a \, t^2 + o(t)}{t^2} = \frac{2 \, a \, t^2 + o(t) + o(t^2)}{t^2}
$$

How can I manage the little o? Can I write:

$$
\frac{2 \, a \, t^2 + o(t) + o(t^2)}{t^2} = \frac{2 \, a \, t^2 + o(t^2)}{t^2} = \frac{2 \, a \, t^2}{t^2}
$$

?

Answer (score 1):

The first expression $\dfrac{at+o(t)}t=a+o(1)$

The second is $\dfrac{at^2+o(t)}{t^2}=a+o(\frac 1t)$

You have not stated whether we study this around $0$ or around $\infty$.

- Around infinity:

You have $\frac 1t\ll 1$ so all terms smaller than $o(1)$ should be ignored.

Therefore you are left with $f(t)=2a+o(1)\to 2a$

- Around $0$:

You have $1\ll \frac 1t$ so everything is dominated by $o(\frac 1t)$

Therefore you are left with $f(t)=o(\frac 1t)$ and you cannot conclude anything.

In general all your little $o(t^\alpha)$ should hold the same power of $t$ to make sense, and you should simply discard everything that is smaller than $t^\alpha$.

E.g. in a neighborhood of $0$

$\require{cancel}4+3t-(t-2)^2+o(t)=4+3t-(\underbrace{\cancel{t^2}}_\text{smaller than o(t)}-4t+4)+o(t)=7t+o(t)$

For instance if you expand this like below up to $t^3$ term:

$\sin(t)+\cos(t)=\Big(t-\underbrace{t^3/6}_\text{useless}+o(t^3)\Big)+\Big(1-t^2/2+o(t^2)\Big)$

You notice that even though you expanded up to two terms for both sin and cos, the $o(t^2)$ in cos expansion forces us to ignore the terms in $t^3$ in sin expansion.

And we are left with $1+t-t^2/2+o(t^2)$

But since the next term in cos expansion is in $t^4=o(t^3)$ we can rewrite:

$\sin(t)+\cos(t)=\Big(t-t^3/6+o(t^3)\Big)+\Big(1-t^2/2+\color{red}{o(t^3)}\Big)=1+t-t^2/2-t^3/6+o(t^3)$

And it is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do  these steps. $2a t^2 + o(t^2)$ is not the same as $2at^2$ (although you can write $2at^2 = 2at^2 + o(t^2)$, because 0 is $o(t^2)$). Also, $2at^2 + o(t) + o(t^2)$ is not the same as $2at^2 + o(t^2)$, because functions dominated by $t^2$ can be increasing as fast as $t$ (for instance, $t$). If something is dominated by $t^2$ then it's also dominated by $t$.

What you can do is think of $o(t^2)$ as the class of functions that is dominated by $t^2$ after some $t$, and then saying $f(t) = o(t^2)$ means $f(t)$ is in the class $o(t^2)$. If you start to reverse this equality, this makes no sense anymore.

So in this case, you need to consider the class $2at^2 + o(t) + o(t^2)$. Think about the functions in this class.

I hope this helps!